# what is "at-syntax" in classes

Tags: typescript, react-native, es6-class

I've recently found this syntax in a project:

```
export function UseDatabase() {
    ...
}

export class LocalDatabase {
    @UseDatabase()
    static async initializeDatabse() {
        ...
    }
    
    ...
}
```

can someone explain me what is this `@-syntax`  used as `@UseDatabase` ?

Comment: These are called `decorators`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: yes thanks for the answer!